# how to fix Circular Dependencies?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, spring-data-jpa

Imagine we have a table called "operation" with a field named "status". This "status" field is actually another table. So, in the "operation" table, we have a foreign key referencing the "status" table.

Now, in the code, whenever we want to view the data from the "operation" table, we need to join these two tables every time, which makes the query heavy.

What I did was writing a cache that, upon service startup, stores all the data from the "status" table internally. Instead of using JPA relationships, I intend to use a custom converter to create my entities.

```
@Entity
public class Operation {

@Id
private Long id;

@Convert(StatusConverter.class)
private StatusEnum status;

}

@Entity
public class StatusEntity{

@Id
private Long id;

private String value;

}

public enum StatusEnum {
    SUCCESS, FAIL
}
```

and its my converter class

```
@Converter
public class StatusConverter implements AttributeConverter<StatusEnum, String> {

private final Cache<StatusEnum, StatusEntity> cache;

public StatusConverter(CacheManager cacheManager) {
    this.cache = cacheManager.getCache();
}

@Override
public String convertToDatabaseColumn(StatusEnum attribute) {
    return cache.get(attribute).getValue();
}

@Override
public StatusEnum convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
    return cache.getKey(dbData);
}
```

But the problem here is that in the CacheManager class, a StatusRepository is defined, which creates a bean circular exception.

```
@Component
public class CacheManager {

private final StatusRepository statusRepository;

    public CacheManager(StatusRepository statusRepository){
 
       this.statusRepository = statusRepository;
    }
}

public interface StatusRepository extends JpaRepository<StatusEntity, Long> {

}
```

its bean cycle when i run project:

1 - entityManagerFactory defined in class path resource
2 - StatusConverter
3 - CacheManager
4 - StatusRepository
5 - inner bean
and again pointer to first bean (1)

Comment: Is the query **really** heavy have you actually measured it? Instead of trying to shoehorn caching in there yourself have you enabled caching for your JPA provider (I assume hibernate)? Enable 2nd level caching for entities instead of making it more complex. IMHO feels like a complex solution for something that is percieved as slow.

Comment: @M.Deinum Due to the large volume of data in the "operation" table and the join between these two tables, it causes slowness. The Hibernate built-in cache is not applicable in this case, and it performs a join operation every time to retrieve data from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use @Lazy (not the best solution) or refactor these classes.

**Lazy:**
The issue you're facing is a common one when dealing with circular dependencies in Spring. In your case, the CacheManager depends on StatusRepository, and StatusRepository is implicitly injected into CacheManager. To resolve this circular dependency, you can make use of constructor injection and the @Lazy annotation. Here's how you can modify your code:

Modify your CacheManager class to accept a lazy initialization of StatusRepository:

```
@Component
public class CacheManager {

    private final Lazy<StatusRepository> statusRepositoryLazy;

    @Autowired
    public CacheManager(Lazy<StatusRepository> statusRepositoryLazy) {
        this.statusRepositoryLazy = statusRepositoryLazy;
    }

    // ... other methods
}
```

Modify your StatusConverter class to accept a CacheManager:

```
@Converter
public class StatusConverter implements AttributeConverter<StatusEnum, String> {

    private final Cache<StatusEnum, StatusEntity> cache;

    @Autowired
    public StatusConverter(CacheManager cacheManager) {
        this.cache = cacheManager.getCache();
    }

    // ... other methods
}
```

Add the @Lazy annotation to your StatusRepository bean definition:

```
@Repository
@Lazy
public interface StatusRepository extends JpaRepository<StatusEntity, Long> {

}
```

By using constructor injection with Lazy, you delay the actual creation of StatusRepository until it's needed, breaking the circular dependency cycle. This should help resolve the "bean cycle" issue you are encountering.

Additionally, make sure that your CacheManager bean is properly defined in your Spring configuration so that it can be injected into other parts of your application where needed.

**Refacor:**
To further refactor your code and eliminate circular dependencies, you can consider the following approach:

Introduce a Service Layer: Create a service layer that abstracts the interactions between your entities and the data access layer. This service layer should handle the business logic and use the repositories to interact with the database. This will help in breaking the direct dependency between the StatusConverter and StatusRepository.

```
@Service
public class OperationService {

    private final OperationRepository operationRepository;

    @Autowired
    public OperationService(OperationRepository operationRepository) {
        this.operationRepository = operationRepository;
    }

    public Operation saveOperation(Operation operation) {
        // Implement your business logic here
        // You can use operationRepository to interact with the database
    }

    // Other service methods...
}
```

Inject the Service into the Converter: Modify your StatusConverter to accept an instance of the OperationService instead of the CacheManager. This way, the converter doesn't directly depend on the repository.

```
@Converter
public class StatusConverter implements AttributeConverter<StatusEnum, String> {

    private final OperationService operationService;

    @Autowired
    public StatusConverter(OperationService operationService) {
        this.operationService = operationService;
    }

    // Implement the conversion logic using operationService
}
```

Use the Service in Your Entity: Modify the Operation entity to utilize the OperationService instead of directly interacting with the repository.

```
@Entity
public class Operation {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private StatusEnum status;

    // ...

    public void setStatus(StatusEnum status) {
        // Implement your business logic here
        this.status = status;
        // You can use operationService to interact with the database
    }

    // ...
}
```

By introducing a service layer, you create a clear separation of concerns, and the circular dependency issue is resolved because the StatusConverter no longer directly depends on the repository. This refactoring also makes your code more modular and maintainable, as business logic is encapsulated within the service layer, and entities focus on representing data rather than database interactions.